# Calculate central q-Binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there any way to calculate the central q-Binomial coefficient efficiently.

For example, $$\binom{2n}{n}_1=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$
First few values of $\binom{2n}{n}_2$ are $1,3,35,1395,200787,109221651$

First few values of $\binom{2n}{n}_3$ are $1,4,130,33880,75913222,1506472167928,267598665689058580$

These can be calculated using the function $QBinomial[2n,n,q]$. But this function works for $n\le10^4$. Is there any property of central q-Binomial coefficient that allows fast calculation for larger $n$?

Comment: Well, to the extent that you can "efficiently" compute $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ then you have: $$\binom{n}{k}_q = \frac{(q^n-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots (q^{n-k+1}-1)}{(q^k-1)(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)}$$

Comment: I need to calculate $\binom{n}{k}_q$ in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Give. That the number of digits base $q$ of this value is $O(n^2),$ you can’t even output the result in $O(n)$ time. But just evaluation the above expression is $O(n)$ operations.

Comment: Thanks. I got it :). yeah, I need to calculate modulo a prime, so it's ok.

Comment: @piepie Did You manage to compute it modulo a prime using the above formula? To me it seems one would have to get rid of the denominator, but I don't see an obvious pattern, how the "smaller" factors in the denominator cancel out against those of the nominator.

Comment: @flonk You have to use Modular multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @piepie I totally forgot about this concept, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an asymptotics could be
$$\binom{2n}{n}_q \sim C_q\, q^{n^2}$$ Computing the coefficient for $n=1000$, the values are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 q & C_q \\
 2 & 3.462746619 \\
 3 & 1.785312342 \\
 4 & 1.452353642 \\
 5 & 1.315213556 \\
 6 & 1.241175663 \\
 7 & 1.195035240 \\
 8 & 1.163594397 \\
 9 & 1.140822757 \\
 10 & 1.123582755 \\
 11 & 1.110084028 \\
 12 & 1.099231752 \\
 13 & 1.090319360 \\
 14 & 1.082870737 \\
 15 & 1.076553491 \\
 16 & 1.071128609 \\
 17 & 1.066419860 \\
 18 & 1.062294483 \\
 19 & 1.058650573 \\
 20 & 1.055408622
\end{array}
\right)$$

Considering the last term in your lists, this would give $116190496$ and $267965804863721413$.